# WCF have multiple connections open

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, wcf, callback

I am creating a WCF service where multiple users connect to it. On my WCF I implement callback contracts so that if a user makes a specific action it can notify other computers that are connected to the same WCF service. So if Company A creates an action on the WCF service then the WCF service will make a callback to all Company A machines that are connected to it. Company B will receive no notifications for example.

**Anyways so far everything works great NOW. what about in the future where there are more connections at the same time? will that cause a problem?**

To avoid that problem will it be better to create a web service where connections are not held open?  *The problem with this approach is the callback mechanism where the web service needs to send a notification to multiple computers* In order to resolve the callback problem I am going to have all machines sending a UDP packet every 10 seconds to the web server. (this will make the router open a port so that the web server can reply in case it needs to) If the web service needs to send a notification to all computers on Company A for instance then it will Send multiple UDP packets. If a computer receives a UDP packet from the web service then it knows it has to make a request to perform the callback. **Should I use this approach?**